# ruby uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting this error:

uninitialized constant GetxmlController::Xmlparse

my code for the class looks like

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML

Class Xmlparse
  def parsetime
    xmlfile = File.new("colors.xml")
    xmldoc = Document.new(xmlfile)
    root = xmldoc.root
    return root
  end
end
```

my controller looks like:

```
class GetxmlController < ApplicationController
  def findxml
    @hxml=Xmlparse.new
    @test1=@hxml.parsetime
  end
end
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't capitalize "Class" in Ruby.

Comment: Um, anyone care to explain the downvote? AFAICT, this *is* why that constant is undefined.

Comment: good catch had to make this a module in order for the controller to see it

Answer (score 2):

try require 'rubygems' before  require "rexml/document"

so it should be look like this

require 'rubygems'
require 'rexml/document'